# Inverse of a given function

Tags: calculus

Let the function $f: R \to R$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2-2$. Find $f^{-1} \{- \infty<x \leq2\}$

What is $f^{-1} \{- \infty<x \leq2\}$ is supposed to mean here? If I take $ - \infty<x \leq2\ $ as domain, the $f$ is not injective in that interval, hence $f^{-1}$ does not exist. Could someone help me with this notation?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$, and suppose $V$ is a subset of $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(V)$ is defined to be the *preimage* of $V$, i.e. it is the set of all $x$ whose image under $f$ is contained in $V$:
$$ f^{-1}(V) = \{ x \in X : f(x) \in V \}.$$

Note that this definition works for arbitrary $f$, bijective or not! There doesn't need to be an inverse function $f^{-1}$. We write it as $f^{-1}$(V)$ purely because it is a convention.

[If $f$ *is* bijective, then the inverse $f^{-1}$ does exist, and you can show that the $f^{-1}(V)$ that I defined is the same as the image of $V$ under the function $f^{-1}$, i.e $f^{-1}(V) = \{ f^{-1}(y) : y \in V \}$.]

Comment: Different authors must define $f^{-1}$ differently. The first two hits on "inverse function definition" in Google had different definitions. Other hits, such as Wolfram requires $f$ to be a bijection. This site, https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/functions/inverses.html allows inverses that aren't functions.

Comment: @Χpẘ Thanks for your comment! I'm familiar with this definition from analysis and topology, where it is quite standard.

Comment: I'm with you, I prefer the definition where the inverse doesn't have to be a function. It's more useful. You can always add a qualifier to the inverse to say whether it's a function or not.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem like standard notation.  I have two guesses:

1. It's a typo and they meant the domain of $f$ to be $-\infty <x\leq \sqrt{2}.$
2. $f^{-1}$ may not be a function, but it is a relation.  And maybe they 
   want the set of all $x$ such that $f(x) \in (-\infty,2]$.